# Is there a way to iterate a for loop until a condition is met? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
until=2000000
Prime=True
total=2
for i in range(3,until,2):
    for t in range(3,i,2):
        if i%t == 0 or i%2==0:
            Prime=False
    if Prime==True:
        total+=i
    elif Prime==False:
        Prime=True
print(total)
```

It is used to find the total of every prime number until two million. This number can be adjusted, and will find the total of every prime until then. (so if until=10, then it would print 19 (2+3+5+7).
However, the logic I have used is very ineffective, as the prime or not sequence looks at every number until the asked for number. Is there a way to make it so that whenever Prime=False there is a way to stop the "for t in range"?

Comment: break statement?

Comment: Did you mean to add `break` underneath `Prime=False`?

Comment: You need to reset `Prime = True` at the beginning of the outer loop.

Comment: It would be easier if you create a separate `is_prime()` function that you called in the loop.

Comment: @Barmar: but `Prime` *is* `True` by the beginning of the outer loop.

Comment: @quamrana Didn't notice that he does that iun the `elif` block -- that's confusing when it can just be initialized each time.

Comment: @Barmar: There are so many things wrong with this code, there's too many to remember all at once.

Comment: `i%2==0` will never be true, because `i` iterates only over odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the break statement:

```
if (condition):
    break;
```

The break statement will force the control to exit the loop.

Answer (score -3):

You can remove the elif statement and there is no need to put i%2==0 because you are only checking odd numbers.

```
until=10
Prime=True
total=2
for i in range(3,until,2):
    for t in range(3,i,2):
        if i%t == 0:
            Prime=False
    if Prime==True:
        total+=i
print(total)
```